# How do I defeat the White Lord with Vitals?

Tags: ether-lords

In Etherlords 1, how do I win the final battle with Vitals? It is an extremely difficult matchup. Vitals only way to win is with mass creatures, and the boss has mass removal every few turns and regenerating, life-stealing fat creatures. Poisoning is not really an option due to the Lord's massive damage output and simultaneous healing.

I have beaten him with all the other races, just not with Vitals. How do I do it?

Comment: I remember playing etherlords 1 a while ago, but as i said, too long to remember these moments. Why dont you give me (us) some more details about the various monsters and cards that he likes to use, and also, your own set of various cards. Just make a list. There's plenty of room.

Answer (score 1):

I found a video with someone playing as vitals against the final boss.

Maybe this will be helpful if you haven't already defeated him, I haven't played the game personally so I can't analyze his card choice, maybe someone else can make better heads or tails of it.